# Implict function in economic models

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm studying an economic model, and I'd like to understand why the authors of the book wrote as follows:

Consider the following equation:

$L_u = \phi(q_{L,t}-Q_t)l_{u,t}$ $~~~~~~[1]$

then, since $q_{L,t} = \frac{\eta}{w_{u,t}}$ and $l_{u,t}= {\frac{w_{u,t}}{\alpha \epsilon^2 L_s^{1- \epsilon}}}^{\frac{1}{\alpha \epsilon -1}}$

You simply plug these values in $[1]$

Then, why the book says: **we obtain the wage rate of low-skilled workers, $w_{u,t}$, as implicitly given by**:

[image]

Why write an implicit function instead of simply solving for $w_{u,t}$?

Finally, why the following derivative has a negative sign and has been written as a ratio?:

[image]

I'd expected $\displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial Q_t} \displaystyle \frac{\partial w}{\partial Q_t}$ instead of $-\displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial Q_t}/ \displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial w_{u,t}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why write an implicit function instead of simply solving for $w_{u,t}$?

Because solving for it explicitly is time consuming and would not yield any new information.

If someone writes $y=x+10$ that is exactly the same information as $x=y-10$. If you have complex function it could take long time to solve it explicitly for some variable. Time is a scarce resource.

If you work with general functions it might even be impossible to explicitly solve for one of the variables although that does not seem to be an issue in your case.

> Finally, why the following derivative has a negative sign and has been written as a ratio?

Because that’s the rule for implicit derivatives along level curve. Generally speaking slope of a level curve can be found realizing that:

$$F(x,y)=c \implies y’ = - \frac{F’_1(x,y)}{F’_2(x,y)}, F’_2 \neq 0$$